# Concrete driveway cured too soon and surface cement washed away

Tags: concrete

I had someone pour a concrete driveway for me.  About 6 hours after it was poured it felt like it had solidified and was now only a little damp so I wanted to start curing it.  I used a hose to spray it using the finest mist setting on the nozzle.  In one area I noticed a few spots where the misting left a darker color and texture from the rest of the slab. When I touched these spots they were not as hard as the rest of the surface and some concrete would come off on my finger. I am guessing in these spots the concrete had not completely set yet or didn't set right and just the misting washed off the top layer of cement.  However on all the other areas of the driveway I tried turning up the water to a full spray and really soaked it without anything like that happening so I don't know why in those few spots just misting would cause problems.
The next day the concrete had dried and these spots had a big difference in color and some difference in texture than the rest of the driveway.  Is there any way I can get this area to look like the rest of the concrete?

Answer (score 1):

Go back in time and wait 24 hours before using the hose. Then use it a couple of times a day for a month.

Other than that, or replacing the whole driveway, probably not. You could do various things to the surface spots, but they are exceedingly unlikely to match the rest of the surface.

Answer (score 0):

6 hours after the last amount of concrete was placed and finished by the installers the concrete surface, although not fully cured, should have set up enough (and been firm enough) to not have been effected by a misting of water. (unless an additive was mixed in to slow the curing time). I'm not pointing fingers, but why after misting the concrete and noting that the water caused a detrimental reaction, why would you continue using the hose by "turning up the water to a full spray and really soaked it...". That doesn't make sense. The only way that might repair the marred areas would be with a grinder with a concrete polishing disc attached. here is a link: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=concrete+polishing